# $r$-regular graph with diameter $2$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $r$-regular graph with $n$-vertices with diameter $2$. I want to find a good bound for $n$ in terms of $r$.

First I observe that it can be said that $n\leq r^2+r$. There are at most $r^2$ vertex which is not adjacent to a vertex. Thus, we get $n-r\leq r^2$ and result follows.

We may also assume that for every non-adjecent two vertex $v_1,v_2$ there is a unique $v_3$ that the path $v_1v_3v_2$ has length $2$. Any reference is welcome. If it is easy to do, any hint or solution is also welcome.

Comment: Did you really mean [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(graph_theory)) or was that a typo for [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html)?

Comment: Why can you assume that "for every non-adjacent two vertex $v_1,v_2$ there is a unique $v_3$ that the path $v_1v_3v_2$ has length $2$"? How does that work out when $r=2$ and $n=4$?

Comment: @bof: Yes, I mean diameter. you are right  $r^2+r+1$. I also write this extra assumption that it can be also assumed if it causes better bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is $r$-regular with diameter two. A vertex $u$ has $r$ neighbours, and each of these neighbours is adjacent to at most $r-1$ vertices at distance two from $u$. So the number of vertices of the graph is at most
$$
  1+ r + r(r-1) = r^2+1.
$$
This bound, a special case of the Moore bound, can only be tight if $r\in\{2,3,7, 57\}$ - famous result due to Hoffman and Singleton. For 2, 3, 7 there unique examples: respectively $C_5$, the Petersen graph and the Hoffman-Singleton graph on 50 vertices. The existence of 57-regular graph of diameter two on 3250 vertices is a very famous open problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me ask you that under the additional assumption which i mentioned, do you see better bound ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I see. The extra assumption force that $n$ is exactly $r^2+1$. In some how I had expected a linear bound, that is why I did not try to improve the polynomial bound.

Comment: @mesel: if $|V(G)|=1+r^2$, then it follows that any two vertices in the graph at distance two have a unique common neighbour (and the graph has girth five). So the additional assumption has no effect.